# Using deferred in jquery asynch POST call

Tags: javascript, jquery, post, jquery-deferred, deferred

I have a button with this event:

```
$("#getSensorsObs").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        postCallOne();
        postCallTwo();
    });
```

I want `postCallTwo` fire when postCallOne has completed with success the first call.

```
function postCallOne() {
  setWait();
  //do something

  return $.post(ADDRESS, {fieldONE : fieldOneVal })
    .done(function (data) {
        console.log("RESPONSE SUCCESS ");
        // do something

    }).error(function(x, t, m) {
            alert(x + ' ' + t + ' ' + m);
        }
    }).then(function (resp) {
        return $.Deferred(function(def){
        def.resolveWith({},[resp == 1,valueSelected]);
    }).promise();
});
```

This is the second function:

```
function postCallTwo() {
  setWait();
  //do something

  return $.post(ADDRESS2, {fieldONE : fieldOneVal })
    .done(function (data) {
        console.log("RESPONSE SUCCESS ");
        // do something

    }).error(function(x, t, m) {
            alert(x + ' ' + t + ' ' + m);
        }
    });
});
```

I have tried with:

```
  $("#button").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        postCallOne.then( function(){postCallTwo();});

    });
```

But I have returned postCallOne.done is not a function.

I don't know very well Deferred, who can help me?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: `postCallOne().done(postCallTwo);` ?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call it like this:

```
$("#button").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    postCallOne().then(function() {postCallTwo()};);

});
```

The problem with the way you have written is the call to postCallTwo will be placed before the deferred is resolved from postCallOne. You need to wait for postCallOne to resolve and then you chain postCallTwo on the success of postCallOne. That's the reason deferreds exist.

Comment: But I have returned Uncaught TypeError: postCallOne.done is not a function

Comment: My bad, please chain it using .then :  `postCallOne.then(function() {postCallTwo()})`

Comment: mmmm now I have .then is not a function

Comment: My bad again `postCallOne().then(function() { postCallTwo()})` .done or .then is not a problem. I forgot to append call parentheses after postCallOne